# Laravel 5.6 Tinker Class '...' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1

Tags: laravel, class, tinker

I'm trying to make a simple class in a fresh-installed Laravel. For this I have created a folder app/Convert and put the php-file there.  The class looks like this:

```
<?php 

namespace App\Convert;

class Converter
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        ...Code
    }
}
```

Now when I try to access it from Tinker:

```
use App\Convert\Converter;
new Converter;
```

I get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App/Convert/Converter' not found in Psy Shell code on line 1
```

What am I doing wrong? As I understand laravel should autoexecute the files inside the app folder and it's subfolders or am I mistaken?

EDIT:
Sorry the first time I wrote it wrong (I just played around so much with the namespaces so I took the wrong version). The problem was actually that the file name was something else than Converter.php, so when I changed it to Converter.php things started to change. I would set the Devon's answer as the correct answer if he put it as an answer not comment. So write it here:

**Name of the file containing class should be the same as the class name. And the path to the file is the same as the namespace path.** (see the Matthew's comment below his answer)

Answer (score 53):

sometimes it is necessary to clear the cache,
this command worked in my case:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

I hope it works for you too

regards

Answer (score 12):

Your namespace in the class differs from how you are trying to import it. You set it as `App\Convert` there. You would need to import it as `App\Convert\Converter`.

The fully qualified class name for a class includes the namespace AND the class name. So, for instance, if you have a class called `Bar` with a namespace of `App\Foo`, the fully qualified class name is `App\Foo\Bar`, and to be able to use it as `Bar`, you'd need to import it as follows:

```
use App\Foo\Bar;
```

Also, as Devon said below, you'd need to have the file containing the class at `app/Foo/Bar.php` for the default Laravel autoloader configuration to pick it up.

Comment: The class would also need to be in the app/Convert/Converter.php file for the PSR-4 autoloader to pick it up.

Comment: thanks, Devon and Matthew. Where in the documentation is it written about the filenames?

Comment: @Timkolm That wouldn't be covered by the Laravel documentation. It's part of how Composer works. In your `composer.json`, there should be a section marked `autoload`, with another section marked `psr-4` nested under it - that maps a particular namespace to the given folder, so `App` will map to your `app/` directory. Subsequent levels of namespacing map to folders under that, so `App\User` would map to `app/User.php`, or `App\Models\User` would map to `app/Models/User.php`. You can read more [here](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4).